# Wpf with database for data coming from webservice

Tags: c#, wpf, database

I really need advice ,i making an app and these are some of the requirements:

- User Enter Login details and it will send to the server using web service

If login details are right it will send the data.

The issue is where to store this data , should i make a database where it will save , or any other way ? and if i make a database another question arises that how can i make a installer which will install everything on one click like a skype installer etc.

I was told me that there is no cookies support in wpf so after login on every request i have to send login details again ? or any other way
Please Guide

Comment: The data can be stored in list or JSON if not too bulky else in a local database (Sterling, etc..)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data you need to store needs to be persisted, you can store them either in a file (typically in json, xml), or in an embedded database like SQLite.

Cookies are a mechanism supported by web browsers. Unless your WPF app embeds a web browser, it is irrelevant. So I guess yes, you need to store the login details, and it should be in a secure form.